# How to decrypt passwords gained by wireshark?

Tags: logging, forensics, wireshark

We are trying to see who is using network VPN.

I used Wireshark to sniff the network, I gained some users and passwords. The usernames were in plain text, but the passwords were in two different encrypted types

One kind like this : `NAME='PlainTextUserName', VALUE=0x9fe513a40a2e169f9930d21b6b0a669d`

At first it looks like a hexadecimal string to me , but I couldn't convert it to what I want. `"0x9fe513a40a2e169f9930d21b6b0a669d"` should be `"udg47cj6"`, but I don't know what should I do and how to convert it .

There are another kind of passwords:
PPP : MS-CHAP Password: PlainTextUserName:"":"":000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:313400C8718E4150100104D9C20000003E2C35ACAFA63D8A:B7587290937FDAA1`

This is another type . (CHAP)
I believe its the password: `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:313400C8718E4150100104D9C20000003E2C35ACAFA63D8A:B7587290937FDAA1`
Looks like a key and a value which needs server's SSL certificate.
For now I'm not looking for this one, I think it's too advanced for me.

Is there a way to convert `"0x9fe513a40a2e169f9930d21b6b0a669d"` to `"udg47cj6"`

Comment: You should first know where this network packet is targeted to. The target application. Then only you can find the mechanism to decrypt it.

Comment: surely if all you're looking to do is see who is using your VPN, the plaintextusername should do the job, you wouldn't need to decrypt the password.

Comment: Thanks @BlueBird ! The packet is a PBK VPN connection . There is a "Guid" value in it : Guid=192FA9C84777454F843788640477B51F
The network packet is targeted to the university server .
Also this is inside the PBK file : http://codepad.org/20QSlQIu

Now what? Thanks !

Comment: @Rory McCune . You're right ! But the passwords redirect us to somewhere else .
BTW I saw a video which used a "chap2asleep" algorithm to decrypt these kind of passwords , But I couldn't find it on the net .

Comment: Password are not easy to convert to human readable format. Some password encryption technique are one way only. Even if it is 2 way, you should know how it was encrypted, you have to become as a hacker to know it. :)

Comment: @BlueBird Thanks again :) !
There is one other thing : if the user uses windowsXP I can see the password as plainText too , but when he/she uses windows7/8 the password is encrypted like that .
So I guess the password is encrypted in clients machine (by that pbk file) before being sent to the server and I am using Kali Linux which sniffs the password from its lan port (before being sent to the server) . There is still not a clue ? :) Sorry for interrupting and tagging .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x9fe513a40a2e169f9930d21b6b0a669d` looks an awful lot like the output of MD5, but you can't be sure since the point of cryptography is to have random-looking output. Basically, the length and the characters look like the output of MD5, and MD5 is one of the more common algorithms, so that's why I'd guess that.

`MD5("udg47cj6")`, however, does not output your hash. So that probably means that a salt was used. (Maybe the username?). Either way, there is no way to "reverse" a hashing algorithm since it is a one-way operation. Your only choice would be to brute force the hash (you would have to brute-force the salt first).

All that work done... it may still not be MD5. We have no way of really knowing without looking at the application's source code.